# AngularJS: 1.2.0rc2 ng-switch does not remove previous content

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

**updated**: made a smaller poc, in plunkr to show the problem without the entire application around it.

[see it here](http://plnkr.co/edit/1QI5jVq6Ikrtk0YsTaMW?p=preview)

issue: `data-ng-switch` works on inline content, but does not remove the previous element when switching using external templates via `data-ng-include`.

*works*

```
<div data-ng-switch="view">
    <div data-ng-switch-when="template1">content 1</div>
    <div data-ng-switch-when="template2">content 2</div>
</div>
```

*doesn't work*

```
<div data-ng-switch="view">
    <div data-ng-switch-when="template1" data-ng-include="'template1.html'"></div>
    <div data-ng-switch-when="template2" data-ng-include="'template2.html'"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does it work when you switch to angular 1.1.5? If yes, then it is a bug.

Comment: i just found out that it works when you don't put the `ng-include` on the same `div` as the `ng-switch`... if you insert a sub `div` with the `ng-include` on it, then it works. but it's not ideal since it adds a new div in the hierarchy which you have to either style ... it is a solution but with heavy compromise

Comment: Personally highly not recommending 1.2.0...

Comment: could you elaborate on why? we need it for some of the newer features like the better routing integration, and an issue in the $http code which can be fixed with 1.2.0 code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best solution I currently found can be seen in the [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/1QI5jVq6Ikrtk0YsTaMW?p=preview)

you basically cannot use `ng-include` on the same dom level as the `ng-switch` anymore. The same goes for other logical directives like `ng-show` `ng-hide`...

adding the `ng-include` on a child node of the `ng-switch-when` element works:

```
<div data-ng-switch="view">
    <div data-ng-switch-when="template1">
        <div data-ng-include="'template1.html'"></div>
    </div>
    <div data-ng-switch-when="template2">
        <div data-ng-include="'template2.html'"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**update**
Should be fixed in .rc3!
This was confirmed as a bug in the angular rc2 version ([confirmation in this google group discussion](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/angular/w7Yo66Q8MU8/HCjru5PGPUIJ)).
The actual bugticket can be found [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3584).

Comment: it's a horrible step backwards if you ask me, but it's the only way to get it to work.

Comment: same here, I've spent a couple of hours trying to figure this out. It seems that this is definitely a bug in angular itself. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Is this still the way things are? I am currently experiencing the same exact issue.